# Как сохранить массив с изображениями в onSaveInstanceState и использовать их в onCreate?

Tags: java, android-studio

Здравствуйте, можете привести пример того, как сохраняют массив с изображениями в **onSaveInstanceState**, а после используется в **onCreate**?

Comment: В каком виде изображения? Ссылки?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб можно в виде ссылок, особой разницы нет